# Submit form with jQuery and redirect to specific URL with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have a webpage that displays search results of houses as either a detailed view (localhost:888#display-as-list) or altogether on a map (localhost:888#display-as-map), with tabs to choose between the two views .

I also have filters to apply to the search, sort by price of property or display 10, 20, 50, etc, items per page. When these filters are changed, the form is submitted and the page refreshes.

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectsortorder,#numberofitems').change(function () {
        $('#sortform').submit();
    });
});
```

The problem with this is that when the page refreshes with the new filters, it reverts to the default detailed view (instead of maybe the map view). Is there a way that I could have the form submit with a redirect URL of sorts so that I can find which tab is selected and then go to either localhost:888#display-as-list or localhost:888#display-as-map?

```
$(function () {
    $('#selectsortorder,#numberofitems').change(function () {
        if ($('li[rel="display-as-list"]').hasClass("current")) {
            $('#sortform#display-as-list').submit();
        }
        else {
            $('#sortform#display-as-map').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm also doing this in MVC/Razor if there is any way to do that more conveniently.

Comment: I would probably add a hidden field to the form and set the value depending on the tab selected.  Then when the form is submitted, you can use that value to set the preferred tab for the user.

Comment: You can also make use of tabs like [Bootstrap Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) to toggle tabs as you wish programmatically rather than depending on URL